# authinfo syntax -- how to include a command in my authinfo file?

Tags: email, emacs, authentication

The online manual states the following:

> The format of an authinfo file is based on the .netrc file specification that is used for FTP login. In addition to the .netrc file standards, the authinfo specification allows for putting commands in the file, as well as using quoted strings for passwords.

However, it never mentions command execution again. How do I replace my password with the output of a command?

### Long Version

I am trying to set up gnus in emacs to read my emails from an IMAP server, and gnus reads its authentication from a `.authinfo` file. Obviously I do not want my password in cleartext in there.

I could go with `.authinfo.gpg`, but I already have my password stored in the system keyring, whence `msmtp` handily retrieves it via `secret-tool lookup`. Is there any way to make gnus use the keyring for receiving mail as well? It seems silly to me to have two different systems in place to encrypt the same password.